# Return list from TypeScript function doing HTTP GET

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, http-get, angular2-http

I have a procedure:

```
products = []
getAllProducts(){
    this.http.get
    (this.baseUrl + '/products').map((resp:Response) => resp.json())
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          const products = data;
          this.products = products;
        },
        err => {}
      );
  }
```

It does work, correctly assigns received list to products variable.
I want to change it into a function, which returns aforementioned list so that I can reuse this code as a service from another component.
I tried something like this:

```
getAllProducts(){
    let localProds = [];
    this.http.get
    (this.baseUrl + '/products').map((resp:Response) => resp.json())
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          const products = data;
          localProds = products;
        },
        err => {alert("ERROR: GET localhost:3000/products "); localProds = ['ERROR'];}
      );
    return localProds;
  }
this.products = this.getAllProducts();
```

I think it should work, though it doesn't. I have two questions:

1) Why the above solution does not work?

2) How to make this function return received list, JSON's list in this case.

EDIT: I agree that question no 2 might have been marked as a duplicate if only I were aware of the fact, that such problem as asynchronous call exists at all. As I did not know that, I still find my whole question (both parts of it) unique for people like me before, newbies to frontend development, who do not know the term "asynchronous call".

Comment: It is a process asyncronous

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

The comment answered your first question ... because it is asynchronous you cannot return the value like that.

This is what my service method looks like:

```
getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And the code that calls the service in the component looks like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._productService.getProducts()
            .subscribe(products => this.products = products,
                       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

The subscribe method causes the http get to execute. When the asynchronous response is received, the function passed in as the first argument to the subscribe method is executed, setting the local products variable to the products returned from the service.

I have a complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.